# C# Mock list of dynamic object as return value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mocking

I have a function which returns an IEnumerable dynamic object

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetNameByRequestIds(List<long> requestIds) {
    return (
    from r in Session.All<Request>()
    where requestIds.Contains(r.REQ_ID)
    select new {
        ReqId = r.REQ_ID,
        Name = r.Name
    }
    ).AsEnumerable();
}
```

In the Unit Test, I mock this by

```
List<dynamic> myList = new List<dynamic>() {
    new {
        ReqId = 1,
        Name = "myName",
    }
};

_db.Setup(x => x.GetNameByRequestIds(It.IsAny<List<long>>())).Returns(myList);
```

But when I executed the following code, it threw out an exception

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'ReqId''

```
var dynamicList = _db.GetNameByRequestIds(myReqIds).ToList();
foreach (var r in dynamicList ) {
    Console.WriteLine(r.ReqId);
    Console.WriteLine(r.Name);
}
```

It works while I query to real DB, but fails in the unit test.

In debug mode

- dynamicList, the type is

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic> {System.Collections.Generic.List<object>}
```

and the r shows

- Type  `<Anonymous Type>`

Answer (score 2):

What mocking framework are you using? That somewhat looks like Moq, however the code to access the mocked results looks incomplete. I've tried the above with Moq (v16.4) and it worked as expected.

What isn't clear in your example is the Type for _db. A cut down example of what works:

```
// The DB wrapper (i.e. you're real code to be mocked away)

public interface IData
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> GetNameByRequestIds(IEnumerable<long> ids);
}

public class Data : IData
{
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetNameByRequestIds(IEnumerable<long> ids)
    {       
        return (
           from r in Session.All<Request>()
           where requestIds.Contains(r.REQ_ID)
           select new {
               ReqId = r.REQ_ID,
               Name = r.Name
           }
        ).AsEnumerable();
    }
}

// Then the code under test... (The service/controller you want to unit test...)

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly IData _db;

    public Consumer(IData db)
    {
       _db = db;
    }

    public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<long> ids)
    {
        foreach (var row in _db.GetNameByRequestIds(ids)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row.ReqId);
            Console.WriteLine(row.Name);
            // Do whatever with the returned data rows...
        }
    }
}   

// Then the Test setup itself...

[Test]
public void TestConsumerDoesSomething()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IData>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.GetNameByRequestIds(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<long>>())).Returns(populate());
    var obj = new Consumer(mock.Object);
    obj.DoSomething();
}

private IEnumerable<dynamic> populate()
{
    return new List<dynamic>
    {
        new {ReqId = 1, Name = "myName"}
    };
}
```

This all appeared to work as you would expect with the method under test ("DoSomething") accessing the data provided by the Mock instead of the "real" DB provider and the mocked dynamic object exposing a ReqId and Name.

Comment: I feel so weird as well, I later ignore the dynamic and create an object. It works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, give this a shot:

Modify your .csproj file for your unit tests to have the following:

`<ItemGroup> <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo"> <_Parameter1>AnotherOtherProjectName</_Parameter1> </AssemblyAttribute> </ItemGroup>`

Do this for the other project(s) as well, (any that are communicating back to your unit test project(s)). This issue is likely one that occurs from two assemblies cross-communicating with dynamic objects.